# script showing progress php

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to know how to create a script using PHP that would execute after x amount of time.

For example:
Player builds a house that takes 2 hours to finish and when he clicks 'build a house' button a script is set up that will count the time and after 2 hours create a house for that certain player, also showing progressbar of how much time is left before the house is ready.

I honestly have no idea how to do this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a database behind your game?

Comment: You can use cronjobs and you can compare the date when the building started and how much time it requires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a database attached to your game project. I would use several database tables. One of them would contain user details (for each player) and another would have timings (build_time):

```
id (int)    item (varchar)    time_to_complete (int)
  1           cottage                60
  2           house                  120
  3           mansion                240
```

Then another table that has the build queue (build_queue)

```
id(int)  user_id(int)  item_id(int)  start_time        is_complete (bool)
1             5             2        14:53 05/03/2013       0
2             6             1        12:02 05/03/2013       1
3             6             2        15:15 05/03/2013       0
```

Then your PHP can check against the items that the game world is building (obv for performance just check the items that are not complete, once complete set the is_complete field to true).

So for a player you would do something like this:

```
SELECT build_queue.*, build_time.time_to_complete 
  INNER JOIN build_time ON item_id = build_time.id
  FROM build_queue WHERE 
     user_id = xx AND is_complete = 0;
```

Then you can check the start time and the time_to_complete field to see if it is almost done for each player.

Answer (score 2):

here is something to **think** about for you:

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['buildStart']) $_SESSION['buildStart'] = time();
if($_SESSION['buildStart'] >= time() + 60*60*2 ) echo "it is done!";
```

Comment: What happens if that player logins from another browser ?

Comment: then the session will need to reside at the db where user credentials are stored. this is not supposed to be a working example lad.

Comment: @MihaiIorga like Gung said it's something for the OP to start thinking about. The original question sounds like a "gimme teh code plz" question

Comment: to get working code for this, the OP should consider asking at a freelancing website. :)